# AngularJS - link model to search string without watching

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

it might be a dumb question but... 
is it possible to link an input to the $location.search() without using a $watch? 
i mean

that would be the html extract

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.search.text"/>
```

this the controller (using controllerAs in the router)

```
this.search = $location.search()
```

and i would like to have the edits reflected in the search string without using a $watch, so something like https://url.blah.blah?text=

This because i hate using watches and i wanna keep my controllers as slim as humanly possible (and the application is pretty big, AND i kinda like this idea)

i know i might just build a directive and shut up, but it sounds too convoluted to me.

Please let me know if it just doesn't make sense :)

Thanks!

Comment: Use a watch in the controller its simple and understandable, I can't think of another way atm. Maybe just change it to a `blur` event or actually clicking the search button?

Comment: @SamV Yeeeah... that's what i'm doing now, but it somewhat an intricate filtering, so it involves multiple watches ( or a big deep watch ) and i don't really like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, in your controller do this:

```
.controller('testCtr', function($location){
   this.search = {
       text:'',
       fn: $location.search.bind($location, 'text');
   };
})
```

And then in your view do this:

```
<div ng-controller="testCtr as vm">
   <input type="text" ng-model="vm.search.text" ng-change="vm.search.fn(vm.search.text)"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You the man! Thank you so much. It might be too Angular-nazi, but don't you think binding should only happen inside a directive?